# remove item from <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am trying to remove an item that is hyperlinked with Jquery and it doesn't seem to be working out that good, can someone shed a little light? Thanks.

HTML Code:

```
<ul id="displayAgency">
    <li><a href="#" agencyId="809" class="itemDelete">Item One</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" agencyId="209" class="itemDelete">Item Two</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" agencyId="409" class="itemDelete">Item Three</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" agencyId="709" class="itemDelete">Item Four</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#displayAgency').click('click', function () {
    $("li itemDelete").remove();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You have `li itemDelete` as your selector, which would try to select a non-existent element named `itemDelete`, instead of `li.itemDelete` which would select an `li` with that class. Is that a typo here or is that in your code?

Comment: You've commented "Actually I would just like to delete the selected li". How is the li being selected?

Comment: Your question should be more clear: you want to remove the inner `a` item or the complete `li`. In both cases there's plenty of Q/A here on SO covering that theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the class selector :

```
$("li .itemDelete").remove(); //Which is a dot
```

You might wanna note that this will delete all `li` no matter which one you click and go back to the top of the page.

Are you looking for this instead?

```
$('#displayAgency .itemDelete').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).remove(); //This remove the 'a' but keep the 'li'
    //$(this).parent().remove(); would remove the 'li'
    //return false; You should use prevent default
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Maybe tell OP the correct way to do it as well as pointing out their error. `$('li').empty();`

Comment: Actually I would just like to delete the selected li, how would that go? Thanks

Comment: @Popnoodles That is another fine answer – usually there are more than one way to a solution…

Comment: Don't misuse `return false` use `event.preventDefault();` instead

Comment: +1 to RokoC.Buljan, `function( event ) { event.preventDefault(); }` would be a better option.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan that one slipped out of my hand, thank!